# converting ZZ (NTL) to a string in C

Tags: c, ntl

ZZ can output in c++ using

```
cout << ZZ;
```

because NTL is a c++ library.

However, how can i output ZZ in C using `printf`, or convert ZZ to a `string`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stringstream` to print (convert) `ZZ` to a `string`:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string zToString(const ZZ &z) {
    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << z;
    return buffer.str();
}
```

EDIT: You can get a C string from a `std::string` using `.c_str()` method, but if you want an independent C string back, then you can `strdup` it:

```
#include <cstring>

char *zzstring = strdup(zToString(z).c_str());
```

and **remember to `free(zzstring)` before it goes out of scope**.

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner, but is this code written in C?

Comment: No, it's C++. If you want a C string, see the edit (a bad mix of C and C++, but this is the only way to get from one to the other).